# Easiest proof $\sup A + \sup B ≤ \sup(A + B).$ No epsilons, sequences. (S.A. pp 18 q1.3.9d)

Tags: real-analysis, intuition

(question 2. http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:DohoRC3-bU8J:www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/UG/IM/MATH2962/r/PDF/tut01s.pdf) [Essay](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/82680)

By definition of A + B and sup(A + B), for all a ∈ A and b ∈ B, 
$\color{seagreen}{a + b} - b \quad \color{seagreen}{\le \quad \sup (A + B)} - b$

> **1.** How can you presage to start with this first line? I acquiesce that this proof behaves.
>   But it feels eerie and fey to subtract $b$ from $\color{seagreen}{a + b} \color{seagreen}{\le \sup (A + B)} $ in the beginning?
>
> **2.** Modus operandi of the proof please?

Hence if we fix $b ∈ B$, then $\color{seagreen}{\sup (A + B)} - b$  is an upper bound for $\color{seagreen}{A + B} - B = A$.

> **3.** Why fix $b ∈ B$? What if we don't? Is there any difference?

And so by definition of $\sup A$, for every $b ∈ B$, $\sup A ≤ \sup (A+ B) − b $.
Rearrange:  $\color{magenta}{b} ≤ \sup(A +B) − \sup A$ for all $b ∈ B$.
Ergo, $\qquad \qquad  \sup(A +B) − \sup A$ is an upper bound for any $\color{magenta}{b}$.

So again by the definition of a supremum: $\color{magenta}{\sup  B} ≤ \sup(A + B) − \sup A \qquad \iff 
\sup A + \sup B ≤ \sup(A + B).$

> **4.** Why is proof of $\sup A + \sup B \ge \sup(A + B)$ easier? Same website contains it.

Since sup A is an upper bound for A, $a ≤ \sup A$  for all a ∈ A.
Similarly, $b ≤ \sup B$ for all b ∈ B. Hence $a + b ≤ \sup A + \sup B$ for all x ∈ A
and y ∈ B.
Ergo $\sup A + \sup B$ is an upper bound for A + B.
Hence by definition of a supremum, $\sup A + \sup B \ge \sup(A + B)$.

Comment: I have now seen quite a few posts from you that challenge and question textbooks, theorems and well-known assertions. It is healthy in mathematics to question why something is right. But I have to say this. I think I mentioned it in one of my answers that you will never have *everything* explained to you. You **must** make a voluntary effort to understand proofs yourself. Next time when you post, instead of asking why this is correct, why don't you try conveying why *you* think it's right so that users may correct your logic. Just a bit of advice. Only if you wish to take it.

Comment: @Ishfaaq: thanks. I know some steps are correct. Not questioning about this. But I don't understand one presages some steps. They feel fey and prescient. I tried thinking about them but still don't grasp it. Is this loathsome?

Comment: No! Of course not! Like I said pondering and digging should be encouraged. If you constantly feel like lines in proofs appear out of nowhere then why don't you try proving them by yourself first before reading the ones in your books. It's just that I sense a slightly obscure attitude which can cause problems in the long run. If you keep approaching proofs aggressively as this you might never get over it. And keep in mind **there are some** things you just have to take for granted. Not everything is justified in Mathematics either. Take it easy mate..\

Comment: @Ishfaaq: thanks for your marvellous advice. always nice to learn about learning math. i try to keep it easy, but i just writhe at taking things for granted. I don't want to be in an exam and fail a question that needs fey/prescient tricks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should understand that many of the steps you've described as "fey and prescient" were probably one of several attempts made while trying to sketch out a proof. The presentation of mathematics will almost always strip away failed attempts, or re-organize what was at first simply scratch work. Admittedly, those comfortable with material will often be able to see the best path in a way that is a bit eerie, but let's look at this problem, and how one might get to this proof in a way that seems a bit less prescient.

A very useful technique when sketching a proof is to try and work backwards, or to reduce your problem to an equivalent one that you can grasp. Let's start with the second one, which is "easier", the following inequality:

$$\sup(A + B) \leq \sup(A) + \sup(B)$$

We ask ourselves what this really means. What do we have to do to prove it? The left-hand side is the supremum of $A+B$. To prove a number is greater than or equal to a supremum, we just need to show it is an upper bound of the same set. This comes directly from the definition of a supremum. So we just want to show that for any $a+b \in A+B$, we have $$a+b \leq \sup(A) + \sup(B)$$

This is clearly true, as $\sup(A) \geq a$, and $\sup(B) \geq b$. So we are done, $\sup(A) + \sup(B)$ is an upper bound on $A+B$, making it larger than the supremum thereof. Clean this up, remove the exposition, and you suddenly have the seemingly prescient short proof.

What does this tell us about the other direction? Namely the inequality

$$\sup(A + B) \geq \sup(A) + \sup(B)$$

Well, we've seen from our previous proof that it's nice to work with things that are bigger than the supremum of a single set. So we try and isolate $\sup(A)$ on the right. We get the equivalent inequality:

$$\sup(A + B)-\sup(B) \geq \sup(A)$$

Note: we haven't proven this, but if we can prove it, we'll be done. Now again, something being bigger than a supremum just means they are an upper bound of the set: so we just need to prove that for any $a\in A$

$$\sup(A + B)-\sup(B) \geq a$$

Again though, we like working with things bigger than a supremum, so we can again rearrange to get the equivalent condition:For any $a \in A$

$$\sup(A + B)- a \geq \sup(B)$$

And now we use our favorite fact, that this is true if and only if for all $a \in A$ we have that $\sup(A+B) - a$ is an upper bound on $B$. Written better, we've shown our original inequality equivalent to: For all $a \in A$, for all $b \in B$:

$$\sup(A + B)- a \geq b$$

or equivalently:For all $a \in A$, for all $b \in B$:

$$\sup(A + B)\geq a + b$$

Which is trivially true. So we reverse the implications, write it up in order, remove our scratchwork, and tada: "fey and prescient" proof!

Note 1: When choosing how to rearrange our inequality, we always tried to get a *positive* supremum term alone on the right. $A$ and $B$ are indistinguishable in their roles in the original claim, so it didn't matter which we isolated first. Note also this goal barred us from ever moving around $\sup(A+B)$ as it would have appeared as a negative, unhelpful to us.

Note 2: Though it worked well enough here, beware of relying to heavily on backwards work. You have to make sure your implications are going the right way. Here we used only equivalencies.

Hope this helps. I'd advise you try this on a delta-epsilon type problem as well, such as proving the quotient law for limits, or the continuity of a polynomial from first principles.

Comment: +upvote consummate answer! how did you learn or know to scrutinize the proof like this? i wish i can!!!