# Prove $\inf (A + B) = \inf A + \inf B$

Tags: real-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How can I prove $\sup(A+B)=\sup A+\sup B$ if $A+B=\{a+b\mid a\in A, b\in B\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4551/how-can-i-prove-supab-sup-a-sup-b-if-ab-ab-mid-a-in-a-b-in-b)

> Prove:
>
> If $A$ and $B$ are nonempty subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and are both bounded above, then $$\operatorname{lub}(A+B)=\operatorname{lub}(A)+\operatorname{lub}(B).$$

I am thinking I need to utilize the fact that $A+B=\{a+b: a \in A, b \in B\}$, I'm just not sure how this gives a proof.

Thanks.

Comment: You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/464/264) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/161783). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful. If you need to format more advanced things, there are many excellent references on LaTeX on the internet, including StackExchange's own [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: Thanks, my LaTeX knowledge is passable, but it definitely needs some work

Comment: $\sup$ is more conventional, see [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supremum)

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82680/ http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4551/ http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30918

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we show that $\sup(A + B) \leq \sup(A) + \sup(B)$:

Let $\gamma$ in $A + B$ be arbitrary. We see that 
$$\gamma = a + b \quad \text{where} \quad a \in A \text{ and } b \in B$$
Now, we know that
$$\sup(A) \geq a \quad \text{and} \quad \sup(B) \geq b$$ 
so it follows that 
$$\gamma = a + b \leq \sup(A) + \sup(B)$$
Since $\gamma$ was arbitrary, this holds for all elements of $A+B$. We must have 
$$\sup(A + B) \leq \sup(A) + \sup(B)$$

Next, we show that $\sup(A + B) \geq \sup(A) + \sup(B)$:

Well, assume the contrary. Then we have
$$ \sup(A + B) < \sup(A) + \sup(B)$$
This implies that for all $\gamma \in A + B$ there exists some $a \in A$ and some $b \in B$ such that $\gamma < a + b$. But $(A + B) \ni \sigma = a + b$, so this is a contradiction.

Putting these two together, we see that $\sup(A + B)  = \sup(A) + \sup(B)$ as we wanted.