# Proving $\sup(A+B)=\sup(A)+\sup(B)$

Tags: calculus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How can I prove $\sup(A+B)=\sup A+\sup B$ if $A+B= \lbrace a+b\mid a\in A, b\in B\rbrace $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4551/how-can-i-prove-supab-sup-a-sup-b-if-ab-ab-mid-a-in-a-b-in-b)

here's a homework question I'm currently working on:

> Let $A,B \subset \mathbb{R}$ non-empty sets bounded from above and from below. Show that
> $A+B$ is upper bounded and that $\sup(A+B)=\sup(A)+\sup(B)$
>
> $A+B=\{a+b:a\in A, b \in B\}$

It was pretty easy to show to $A+B$ is upper-bounded by $\sup(A)+\sup(B)$, but I'm not quite sure how to prove that this is also the supremum. Any hints?

Thanks!

Comment: Let $c$ some upper bound of $A + B$. Then for $a \in A$ $c-a$ is an upper bound of $B$, therefore ...

Comment: I think that I saw at least *two* of these questions posted on the site before.

Comment: Take $(a_n)_n \subset A$ to be the sequence such that $\lim_n a_n = \sup(A)$, similarly for $b_n$. What can you say about $(a_n+b_n)_n$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well $a+b\leq \sup(A)+sup(B)$ then $\sup(A+B) \leq \sup (A)+\sup(B)$ for the other inequality consider $a_{\epsilon}\in A$ such that $ a_{\epsilon}>\sup A- \epsilon /2$ and $b_{\epsilon}\in B$ such that $ b_{\epsilon}>\sup B- \epsilon /2$ then

$\sup(A+B)\geq a_{\epsilon}+b_\epsilon>\sup A +\sup B-\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$ then

$\sup(A+B)\geq \sup A +\sup B$ $\blacksquare$

Comment: Isnt't there a dot missing prior to "for the other..."?