# Why is $L(P,f)+L(P,g) \le L(P,f+g) \le U(P,f+g) \le U(P,f)+U(P,g)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $R \subset \Bbb{R}^n$ and $f,g$ be two integrable functions from $R\to \Bbb{R}$ , in a proof of a property of integrals Rudin writes the following: $$L(P,f)+L(P,g) \le L(P,f+g) \le U(P,f+g) \le U(P,f)+U(P,g)$$ where $P$ is any partition. The $\le$ between  $L(P,f+g)$  and $U(P,f+g)$ is clear but why is it that  $L(P,f)+L(P,g) \le L(P,f+g)$  and $U(P,f+g) \le U(P,f)+U(P,g)$ isn't it easy to see by expanding the sums to see that they are equal since $\sup(f+g)=\sup(f)+\sup(g)$ (and similarly for the $\inf$) ? Am I missing something or did Rudin just write it this way since it won't make a difference?

Note: Rudin's proof is over an interval, but the multivariable case is similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made a small error. It is true that $\sup(f+g) \leq \sup f + \sup g$. The inequality may be strict though. (Can you come up with an example for yourself? Consider $f$ and $g$ which obtain their maxima at different places.)

Comment: I seem to have ignored the fact the $\sup$ is taken over each subinterval, what still confuses me though is: what is missing in the conditions for the relation $\sup(f+g)=\sup(f)+\sup(g)$ to hold, since it only requires the functions to be bounded which is true here. Here is a proof : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4551/how-can-i-prove-supab-sup-a-sup-b-if-ab-ab-mid-a-in-a-b-in-b

Comment: You are confusing yourself with notation, $\sup(f+g)$ and $\sup(A+B)$ mean different things. We have $\sup_X(f+g) = \sup\{f(x)+g(x) : x \in X \}$ while $\sup(A+B) =\sup\{a+b: a \in A, b \in B\}$. It is true that $\sup(f(X) + g(X)) = \sup f(X) + \sup g(X)$ where $f(X),g(X)$ denote the images (ranges) of $f,g$ respectively.

Comment: In Particular, $(f+g)(X) \neq f(X)+g(X)$.

Comment: Oh I get it now, thank you!