# What is $sup{ (-1)^n + 1/n} $?

Tags: real-analysis

My doubt is that $\sup (A+B) = \sup A + \sup B$.
So, if we consider  $A =(-1)^n$ and $B=\frac{1}{n},$

then $\sup A = 1 $  and   $\sup B = 1$.
So will $\sup (A+B) = \sup{ (-1)^n + 1/n}  = \sup (-1)^n   +  \sup \frac{1}{n} = 1+1 =2 ?$

Is this correct or have I misunderstood somewhere please explain?

Also could you please provide the correct method to solve the above problem?

Comment: What does "SUP" mean here?

Comment: Supremum or least upper bound

Comment: See e.g. [How can I prove $\sup(A+B)=\sup A+\sup B$ if $A+B=\{a+b\mid a\in A, b\in B\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4551/how-can-i-prove-supab-sup-a-sup-b-if-ab-ab-mid-a-in-a-b-in-b) for proof of the statement $\sup(A+B)=\sup(A)+\sup(B)$.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth did you read the body of my question?

Comment: Yes, I did. You said you had doubt about $\sup(A+B)=\sup(A)+\sup(B)$, so I provided a link about that.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth I don't need the proof , what I need is the clarification of the e.g I gave

Comment: So you don't actually have doubt that $\sup(A+B)=\sup A + \sup B$? I was just providing that link to address that doubt, not as an answer to your question.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth yeah I have no doubt regarding that . Thanks for the help

Comment: $\newcommand{\Z}{: n\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}}$By the way, that theorem isn't applicable like that here since $\{(-1)^n + 1/n  \Z \} \ne \{ (-1)^n \Z \} + \{ 1/n \Z \}$. I.e. the set you need the sup of is not actually equal to $A+B$. (Where $A = \{ (-1)^n \Z \}$ and $B = \{1/n \Z \}$.)

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth why? Could you please explain that , this was my real problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\s}{: n\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}}$ If $A = \{ (-1)^n \s \}$ and $B = \{ 1/n \s \}$, it is **not** true that $\{ (-1)^n + 1/n \s \}$ equals $A+B$. This is because $A+B$ refers to the set of all sums of pairs of elements of $A$ and $B$ where the "$n$" *can be different for each*. That is, $A+B = \{ (-1)^{n_1} + 1/n_2 : n_1, n_2\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}\}$, whereas in $\{ (-1)^n + 1/n \s \}$, the "$n$" is the same in both terms.

For example, $(-1)^3 + 1/2 = -1/2$ is in $A+B$ but you can show that $-1/2$ is *not* in $\{ (-1)^n + 1/n \s \}$.

Thus, your reasoning was unfortunately incorrect.

(Written using functions, you can say that $\sup\limits_n (f(n)+g(n))$ in general does not equal $\sup\limits_n f(n)+\sup\limits_n g(n)$.)

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that in the statement
$$
\sup (A + B) = \sup A + \sup B
$$
the definition of "$+$" is given by 
$$
A+B=\{a+b\mid a\in A, b\in B\},
$$
and $A$ and $B$ are **sets** (of real numbers)
.

You, in trying to apply it, appear to be adding two **sequences** termwise, i.e., you're defining a new sequence 
$$
(A+B)_n = A_n + B_n
$$
With this definition of addition (and the implied notion that "sup" of a sequence is the sup of the set of items in the sequence) the "theorem" is no longer a theorem, as your counterexample shows.

Comment: Thanks for you help

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use [this property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494502/prove-that-supab-supa-supb-and-why-does-supab-exist). This is because were are not talking about elements in sets, but about sequences which depend on the same $n$, therefore, these sequences are not 'disjoined'.

An easy way to look at this problem is that you want to "maximize" both $(-1)^n$ and $1/n$ simultaneously. Notice that both are bounded by $1$, so we want to show that we can find $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that both components are equal to one. Notice that for $(-1)^n=1$, we must have that $n$ is even, i.e. $n=2k$. Substituting the later into the second component, we have $\frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{2k}$, where $\sup\big({\frac{1}{2k}}\big) = \frac{1}{2}$, where $k=1$, and thus $n = 2k = 2$. Hence, 
\begin{equation}
\sup\bigg(\frac{1}{n} + (-1)^n\bigg) = \frac{1}{2} + 1 = 1\frac{1}{2}
\end{equation}

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: yeah, I have found my mistake