# properties of the norm of operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, supremum-and-infimum

In this question $\mathcal{H}$ stands for a Hilbert space over $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, with inner product $\langle\cdot\;| \;\cdot\rangle$ and the norm $\|\cdot\|$ and let $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ the algebra of all bounded linear operators from $\mathcal{H}$ to $\mathcal{H}$.

We recall that for $T\in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$, the norm of $T$ is given by
$$\|T\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Tx\|$$
Are the following equalities true
$$(\displaystyle \sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Tx\|)^2=\displaystyle \sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Tx\|^2,\;\;\;(\displaystyle \sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Tx\|)^{1/2}=\displaystyle \sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Tx\|^{1/2}\;??$$
It is clear that $\{\|Tx\|;\;\|x\|=1\}\subseteq B(0,\|T\|)$, so it is bounded.

Thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider an increasing and left continuous function $$f : \mathbb{R} \cup \{ \pm \infty \}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R} \cup \{ \pm \infty\}.$$ Then for any collection of elements $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathbb{R}\cup \{ \pm \infty \}$ 
$$
f(\sup \{\mathcal{A} \}) = \sup f(\mathcal{A}).
$$

Indeed $$f(\sup \{\mathcal{A} \}) \ge f(a), \ \ \forall a \in \mathcal{A}$$ which gives one inequality. The second inequality follows from left continuity by taking a sequence $$a_k \nearrow \sup \{\mathcal{A} \}$$ so that 
$$
f(\sup \{\mathcal{A} \}) = \lim f(a_k) \le \sup f(\mathcal{A}).
$$